# Can a magnetic field alone be used to move a metallic object within a contained tube?

Tags: magnetic-fields

Is it possible to make a metallic object move in a circular contained tube around and around in which a magnetic field is setup to cause the metallic object to move through the electric field within the tube through magnetic forces alone?  If not, what other forces must be present to make the object move around and around in the circular tube?

Comment: So long as the tube is [not a superconductor](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/36421/does-a-material-exist-that-reduces-a-magnetic-field-without-being-affected-by-th), the magnetic field alone could cause the magnetizable object to move.

Comment: So, what if on outside of the tube, the conductor of electricity surrounds the tube and draws in the energy from the metallic object's friction created within the tube that is not a superconductor?  Could energy be channeled?